# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int with inner join statement in C#

Tags: c#

[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX1Xw.png)

```
myCon = new SqlConnection(@"myconnectionstring");
myCon.Open();

string id_trender = "UPDATE b SET b.id_trender = @a.id_trender FROM trenders a JOIN adjustments b ON a.dim_name_trender = b.name";
//var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(id_trender, myCon);

cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustments(id_trender) VALUES" + "(@id_trender)", myCon);
// cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_trender", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_trender;
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_trender", id_trender));

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCon.Close();
```

I get this error when making a connection to my database in SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a two tables with `id_trender` in one table and I'm using an inner join to insert the `id_trender` into another table. Basically, I want to match the id on `trender` table to the name in `adjustments` table.

Here is my table structure in SQL:

Adjustments table:

```
id, name, id_trender
```

Trenders table:

```
dim_name_trender, id_trender
```

Comment: @id_trender is expected to contain a value of type interger not an sql command

Comment: Hi Steve, sorry I'm new to SQL and C# not sure how to add stuff without value, Do i need to convert to an int?

Comment: Do I need to cast the id as an INT in the update statement?

Comment: Make sure the value you are passing for id_trender is INT. Looks like it is passing a non-numeric value.

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita I'm not sure how I do that?

Comment: @kjjjkjjj just put a breakpoint to below line of code and debug.

cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_trender", id_trender));

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita I put the breakpoint in and it reaches that point

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita  when I put breakpoint at myCon.Close(); it seems to throw the error then

Comment: What was the value you got for "id_trender" in the line i mentioned?

Comment: @barr j    I tried to cast like this: update b set CAST (b.id_trender AS int) = CAST(a.id_trender AS INT) FROM trenders a JOIN adjustments b ON a.dim_name_trender = b.name

Comment: @Barr J I still get error saying input string was not in correct format

Answer (score 0):

Solution was just to have the update statement because I am already connected to the server:
 string id_trender = "update b set b.id_trender = a.id_trender FROM trenders a JOIN adjustments b ON a.dim_name_trender = b.name";

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO adjustments(id_trender) VALUES @id_trender)", myCon);
```

Comment: That didn't solve it either, still get input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Any other suggestions?